# Retrieving metadata (table name) from a SQL statement

Tags: c#, java, .net, database, visual-studio-2008

I am using Visual Studio 2008.

I have created a Winforms application, and I am trying to extract the table name from a SQL statement.

```
con = new SqlConnection(connString);
String queryString = "Select CUSTOMER_NAME from CUSTOMER_DETAIL";
```

Is there any function to do so?

Please help me out.

Comment: Hi @C_J, SQL queries can be extremely complicated at times, and have multiple tables etc, what exactly are you trying to do?  Perhaps be a bit more specific.

Comment: in Java There is ResultSetMetaData interface is there anything like this interface or class which give metadata about the table

Comment: @C_J in the case my answer doesn't help, I have re-tagged the question (added Java tag), I think that programmer having experience with both C# and Java will help you more. I've no experience in Java and my answer is based on what I have read ([link's here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSetMetaData.html)) about the `ResultSetMetaData` so I might be mistaken.

Comment: Thanxx for all ur precious views.Task achieved will post the answer after 8 hrs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's good that you have mentioned Java's [ResultSetMetaData](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSetMetaData.html). Quoting that link:

> public interface ResultSetMetaData
>
> An object that can be used to get information about the types and
> properties of the columns in a ResultSet object.

As for C#, you can get the same information using the [DataColumn  Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.aspx).

`DataType` Property of `DataColumn` class can be used to get (and to set) the type of data stored in column, `AllowDBNull` can be used to get (and set) the value that indicates whether null values are allowed in this column, etc... To get the full list of `DataColumn` properties follow the link I have posted above.

Sample code (gets column datatype):

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connString);
String queryString = "Select CUSTOMER_NAME from CUSTOMER_DETAIL";
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(queryString, con);
DataTable myTable = new DataTable();
myTable.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());
DataColumn column = myTable.Columns[0]; // zero based index of column, alternatively use column name
string typeOfColumn = column.DataType.Name; // or column.DataType.FullName to get the fully qualified name of the System.Type
```

Comment: Thanx @Niko,I have created a method which gives me the tablename from simple query(Select * from Tablename) now i am trying to retrieve tablename from a Join query

Comment: @C_J so the question was only about Table names? asking because after reading one of your comments I thought `DataColumn` Class was the one you were looking for.

Comment: ,I needed the table name in the SQL String query.that all i wanted as i was trying to create Retrieval technique in CRUD

Answer (score 1):

I found this site that has a GREAT parser....

http://www.sqlparser.com/

well worth it. Works a treat......

Answer (score 1):

- Try using "Interop - SQLDMO"
- Else you might have to write your own custom class
- Rather than using a function that evaluates a string (in which the query is written), I'd suggest you make a custom SQL query builder class (as per your requirements) and then write your methods or extensions to achieve your goal of getting metadata of the query
- That is if you have no option but to use SQL-queries directly in your c# code

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

This is the Method which gives us tablename just change the SQL query string,connection String 
Works with simple query,Joins too

```
 public static List<string> getTablenames(string connString,string QueryString)
    {

        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connString);
        con.Open();
        DataTable dt = con.GetSchema("Tables");

        List<string> getTableName = new List<string>();
        List<string> tablenames = new List<string>();

        foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
        {
           tablenames.Add(dr[2].ToString());
        }
        for (int ii = 0; ii < dt.Rows.Count; ii++)
        {
            string myTable = tablenames[ii];
            Boolean checkMyTable = QueryString.Contains(myTable);
            if (checkMyTable == true)
            {
                    getTableName.Add(myTable);
            }
        }
        con.Close();
        return getTableName;
    }
```

thanxx StackoverFlow